# Automatically replace open quote with accent

Tags: punctuation, emacs, auctex

Shaloha,

My Emacs/AUCTeX combination used to automatically replace a single open quote ' with an accent `, as is required by LaTeX. Many machines and .emacs files later, it doesn't do that anymore. I suppose it's an AUCTeX option, but I couldn't find it. (I thought it would be in the Tex Quote AUCTeX customization menu, but no.)

**How can I make the single open quote ' automatically replaced by `?**

Comment: I just realized that I might be misremembering; maybe my Emacs/AUCTeX combo only automatically replaced double quotes. It still does that. The question stands though.

Comment: If you really want to automatically insert a "`" by pressing "'" you can put this in your `.emacs`: `(define-key TeX-mode-map "'" "`")` but I'm not sure this is really a good idea.  "'" is different from "`", LaTeX doesn't require "`" instead of "'".

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Emacs could obviously reolace the character but is that really what you mean? `'` is an apostrophe as in `it's` or a single right _close_ quote. Or perhaps you mean you want to just replace `'` by `\`` on every other occasion so `'foo'` turns in to `\`foo'` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I suppose you're right. What about replacing ' by ` whenever it's the first character of a new word?

Comment: @QuinnCulver don't you have the backtick in your keyboard layout? Anyway, if you want I can provide you a function for inserting ` by pressing `'` when the preceding character isn't a letter.

Comment: @giordano I have the backtick. Unfortunately, I also have the habit of begining quotes with '. I think this is why AUCTeX replaces opening double quotes. That function would be quite helpful. If you provide it as an answer, I'll try it and probably accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code to your `.emacs`. It binds the `'` key to a function which inserts an apostrophe if the preceding char is a letter, a digit, a backslash (because `` \` `` and `\'` give two different accents in LaTeX) or another apostrophe (to cater for ``` LaTeX ``quotes'' ```), a backtick otherwise.

```lisp
(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(define-key TeX-mode-map "'"
     '(lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (if (string-match "\\([[:alnum:]]\\|\\\\\\|'\\)" (string (char-before)))
        (insert "'")
      (insert  "`")))))
```