# Automatically replace input with accents by their safe code for accents

Tags: emacs, auctex, accents

I was checking this: [Automatically replace open quote with accent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120548/automatically-replace-open-quote-with-accent), and it is actually similar to what I want. Since I'm starting with Emacs, and everything seems admissible to be automatized. Because I write spanish text, I type accents like for example `á`, `é` or `í`.
I would like to have the instant automatic translation between the characters with an accent and their equivalent version using the slash form.
So for instance, if I type `á` then it'll be translated to `\'a` and so on.

Comment: It is no more annoying nowadays if you  use `utf8` encoding. All modern systems know about `utf8`.  I've been typing accented letters without any  problem for more than twenty years, and it makes the code much more readable.

Comment: I think this would be a step backward, really. We *want* people to use UTF-8 (and I hope you are when using Emacs!). And it is mostly a breeze to convert from one encoding to another (assuming it was encoded well to begin with). Even going from UTF-8 to the special world of TeX markup for a specific `.tex` file is not tricky if it should ever become necessary.

Comment: If you want, you can use `M-x replace-string` to change every accent after typeset.

Answer (score 3):

I'll echo what the commenters suggest and say that you would be better off writing the accents as you normally would and encoding the document in UTF-8:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Tells all the other packages that the document language is Spanish. It also  changes hyphenation rules and quotation marks. The choose the mexico or spain option depending on whether you want a period or a comma as a decimal separator in numbers. 
\def\spanishoptions{mexico}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
% Encodes the input as UTF-8. 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Encodes the fonts as T1
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
ÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ áéíóúñ

\end{document}
```

See also the answers to the questions [How to write directly French characters in Emacs and print them in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26716/3731) and
[Why should I use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/677/3731) for more information.